# I think my family and I were deported (but not sure) from Canada when I was 16. I need info to go home

Tags: canada

Background: I was 16 at the time as a Pakistani refugee with my family. Things didn't work out and we were given 30 days to leave the country. We left within the first week (to the US by border and stayed there 2 weeks before going to Pakistan). I had my name permanently changed in 2007 as well. Since then, my parents passed away in Pakistan and I'm not completely sure what the status of my case was or is. I just heard that I personally needed to wait 10 years to become eligible again.

I've read from multiple sources and spoken to an immigration consultant about this issue. All he said was that I've spent over 10 years here and my biometrics (fingerprints) as well as records wouldn't work against me since I was a dependent back then. I'm not sure if that's correct or not. Further information, I'm a secret ex-muslim and have had trouble adjusting to the culture in Pakistan, which is why I wish to return back to my home. I'm also a bachelor degree holder and speak English natively.

Is there any hope for me to go to Canada again?

Comment: To emigrate there, or to simply visit?

Comment: How long were you in Canada before leaving?

Comment: I lived in Canada for 5 years. Before that I was in the US for 6 years. and before that, Saudi Arabia. In short, things didn't work out in the US(we were immagrants) after 9/11 so my parents brought us to Canada(as refugees). Things didn't work out in Canada neither, and we had to go to their home country of Pakistan. They passed away shortly after we came to Pakistan and I was raised with my paternal family afterwards. Now I wish to find a way to go back perminantly, but I don't know if it's possible. my past history wont help much(lawyers told me).

Comment: I'm saving up and working on my case to immagrate for a work visa, but the doubts that stand are with the biometric (fingerprint) data. Would they hinder my process in anyway? I'm not sure if we were deported or if we left legally without breaking any rules. Did i need to wait 10 years to go back, or is the door closed perminantly?

Comment: My main doubt is weather I have a chance to ever return home again. I prefer Canada or Usa equally(I consider both my homes), but a lawyer told me last year that polices for muslim countries are far too strict(I"m not sure if that's true or not). He claimed that although we were asked to leave Canada, we didnt break any laws so we had to wait 10 years before reapplying to emigrate/immigrate. If we'd broken laws, it wouldve been a permanent ban. What's the case for me here. Please feel free to ask more questions if that helps

Comment: The Canadian government is forgiving of many things, but not of lying or withholding significant information.  (E.g. just this month, the Supreme Court removed 95 year old [Helmut Oberlander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmut_Oberlander#Revocation_of_citizenship)'s citizenship because he didn't report his WWII activities at the time of his immigration in 1954.  In theory he can now be deported to Germany for trial there.  Note that it was for *lying* about his activity, not the activity itself.)  If you *do* get an interview, do mention everything you know, and if you're not sure, say so.